# Is it "close the door" or "shut the door"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

I am confused about which one to use. Do the phrases have the same meanings or different meanings?

> 1. **Close** the door.
> 2. **Shut** the door.

Comment: Either is acceptable, however an intentional misreading of **close the door** might result in someone only partially closing the door, whereas I would always interpret **shut the door** as closing it *completely*.

Comment: It could also imply force. Close the door might mean to be gentle, whereas shut the door might imply doing so forcefully. Depends on the context (i.e., Close the door, the baby is sleeping, vs. Shut the door, you're letting the cold air in).

Comment: Is it "eat your dinner" or "have your dinner"? Is it "enter your password" or "key in your password"? Is it "raising a barrier/wall" or "erecting a barrier/wall"? Are they your children or are they your kids? Would you like to have pasta or noodles?

Comment: "Dog that hatch!" ~ unknown sailor.

Comment: It is not off-topic but an interesting question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are other phrases that commonly employ one of these and not the other, *close* and *shut* have the same meaning and can be used interchangeably in almost all cases.

If one were to replace *shut* with *close* in the expression "Shut up!", it would no longer retain its meaning and would only serve to confuse, although someone may find the alteration amusing, lessening the rudeness of the saying.

Since the act of *closing* and *shutting* would require the same operation and the state of being *closed* is nearly always identical to it being *shut*, you can feel confident using them as near perfect synonyms.

In an effort to distinguish them, I will say that a thing that is *closed* brings to mind the idea that its contents are *enclosed*, or inside. It also refers to hours of operation or availability, such as in "that shop is closed", in a way that shut cannot express on its own. An older phrase that encompasses this concept is "that shop is shut up for the day" (closed up works here, too) or "that shops looks like it's shut down".

So really, the differences happen when you get into the other definitions these words have and their separate connotations. The word lover enjoys using English because most words have many definitions. A side effect of having multiple meanings is that when using a word for its clearly intended meaning, one can choose a word that has another meaning that also applies to the situation (and often, this is where a connotation can come from). So knowing how your words are used in other contexts gives you a better idea which synonym to choose for your context.

These are cases where the words retain the close/shut meaning, but where the meaning of the phrases they're in are not identical:

close, shut; close up (temporary closing, in drawing - to bring lines together/close space), shut up (for the night [it would not suffice to say shut up without naming some condition of the shutting]) (temporary closing and shelter & protection); close down, shut down (permanent closing, with shut down sounding more permanent); close the windows, shut the windows (same meaning, but shut sounds a bit harsher);

Hopefully, someone else can improve on this list starter.

Comment: See my comments above: essentially, I'd say that _close_ is preferable to _shut_ when grading it, as in _shut the door __halfway___ and _close the door __halfway___ - the former is almost infelicitous, and definitely questionable.

Also: **close up** and **shut up** don't allow substitution because they're idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

They mean the same thing in your example, and in other situations too. For example.

"Shut your eyes" is the same as "close your eyes."
They are also synonymous when referring to windows, mouths and shops.

However, you wouldn't say "close off the electricity," even though you could say "shut off the electricity" (or motor or water supply).

Comment: I think there's a slight nuanced difference, as per my comment above - _close_, I think, has more potential to be graded as in _close the door __a little___ and _close your eyes __halfway___.

Comment: @jimsug That's true. On the other hand, if your boss asks you to come into their office and close the door I bet you don't ask if they mean halfway. :)

Comment: Shut seems more "violent" to me. They're not 100% synonymous.

Comment: "On the other hand, if your boss asks you to come into their office and close the door I bet you don't ask if they mean halfway". The question is more about the etymological meaning, not the usage.

Comment: @Quidam, the OP asks which one to "use". That sounds like usage to me.

Comment: . You're right.

Answer (score -2):

Shut is used to overlap or cover which results not allowing to come out or get in
Like shutters do 
Close is used to bring near or remove gap which results unavailability of path or way to pass 
Like come closer 
They are too close

Both shut n close are different in nature but results into same meaning sometimes

Comment: Shut used for "cover", I'm not convinced. Do you have examples or references?